# Implementing a regression function on a multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, logistic-regression

I'm going through an algorithm that does regression on some training data.
The training dataset *X* consists of *n* samples, where n = 10.
Each sample *x[i]* from *X* is an array consisting of, say, 4 features. 
This means that *X* is a 2D array with 10 rows and 4 columns.

One of the lines in the algorithm says, in the midst of a loop using iterator *j*:

> Fit the regression function *g_j^h(x)*
>   by weighted least-squares of the
>   working response vector *z[i][j]* to
>   *x[i]* with weights *w[i][j]* on the
>   training data.

This is Step (2)(a)(ii), on this algorithm: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5C6P.png]

In this case, the index *i* represents the sample out of the *n* samples, and *j* is a loop iterator.

My question is - how can *g_j(x)* be applied to a 2D array? What is the practical application of this formula on arrays?

With 10 samples x 4 features each, will I end up calculating *g_j(x)* 10 times, and for each of those times, will each of the 4 features per sample also have their own *g* function? For a total of 40 different *g* functions?